# Saving state of a nested-accordion menu after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, accordion, repeater

I have a nested accordion menu which i've populated with nested asp:Repeater controls on my page. When i've clicked the asp:Imagebutton, the page postbacks and my nested accordion menu closes. Is there any way to prevent the accordion menus close and save its state. And yes i've checked the other Questions but i cannot find any nested accordion one.

Accordion Menu

```
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="nestedAccordion">
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptCategories_ItemDataBound" ID="rptCategories">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <h2><%#Eval("Name")%></h2>
                        <div>
                            <asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptSubCategories_ItemDataBound" ID="rptSubCategories">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <h3 subcategoryid="<%#Eval("Id")%>"><%#Eval("Name")%></h3>
                                    <div class="SubCat" id="products" subcategoryid="<%#Eval("Id")%>" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptProducts_ItemCommand" ID="rptProducts">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <div class="SubCat" subcategoryid="<%#Eval("SubCategoryId")%>" style="float: left; cursor: pointer">
                                                    <asp:ImageButton class="prod1" productid='<%#Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="Select" EnableViewState="true" CssClass="prodimgs" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("Member/{0}",Eval("ImageUrlTiny"))%>' ID="btnImageUrl" runat="server" />
                                                </div>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>

            </div>

        </div>
```

And i make it slide up and down by the jquery codes below

JQuery

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        var $parents = $('#nestedAccordion').find('div');
        var $childs = $('#nestedAccordion h3').find('div');
        var parentDivs = $('#nestedAccordion div'),
          childDivs = $('#nestedAccordion h3').siblings('div');
        parentDivs2 = $('#nestedAccordion div div');
        parentDivs3 = $('#nestedAccordion div div div');

        $('#nestedAccordion h2').click(function () {
            $parents.slideUp();

            if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
                $(this).next().slideDown();
            } else {
                $(this).next().slideUp();
            }
        });
        $('#nestedAccordion h3').click(function () {
            var subcatId = $(this).attr("SubCategoryId");
            $childs.slideUp();
            $(this).siblings('div').slideUp();
            if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
                $(this).next().slideDown();
            } else {
                $(this).next().slideUp();
            }
            $(".SubCat[SubCategoryId=" + subcatId + "]").css("display", "block");

            var itemIndex = subcatId;
            $("#hidMenuItem").val(itemIndex);
        });
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: sounds like you would be better using ajax. Alternative is store the accordion states in localStorage.

Comment: thanks for response! what do you mean about localStorage? Cookie or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been solved this issue with two hidden fields. One for subcategory id and the other one for category id

As you can see i have a repeater and i post backed with the image button inside it. And i defined "categoryid" and "subcategoryid" attributes. After that i will use that attributes to open my accordion menu again.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnCategoryId" />
                    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnSubCategoryId" />
                    <div id="menu">
                        <div id="nestedAccordion">
                            <asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptCategories_ItemDataBound" ID="rptCategories">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <h2 categoryid="<%#Eval("Id")%>"><%#Eval("Name")%>
                                        <img align="right" src='images/frontend/buyukkapali.png'>
                                    </h2>
                                    <div class="Cat" categoryid="<%#Eval("Id")%>">
                                        <asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptSubCategories_ItemDataBound" ID="rptSubCategories">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <h3 subcategoryid="<%#Eval("Id")%>"><%#Eval("Name")%><img align="right" class="oklar" src='images/frontend/close.png'></h3>
                                                <div class="SubCat" id="products" subcategoryid="<%#Eval("Id")%>" style="width: 100%;">
                                                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptProducts_ItemCommand" ID="rptProducts">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <div class="SubCat" subcategoryid="<%#Eval("SubCategoryId")%>" style="float: left; cursor: pointer">
                                                                <asp:ImageButton class="prod1" productid='<%#Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="Select" EnableViewState="true" CssClass="prodimgs" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("Member/{0}",Eval("ImageUrlTiny"))%>' ID="btnImageUrl" runat="server" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                                </div>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>

                        </div>

                    </div>
```

And Here is my .cs file. I set the hiddenfields value by sub category id and the category id each row command.

```
protected void rptProducts_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            ...

            hdnCategoryId.Value = productModel.CategoryId.ToString();
            hdnSubCategoryId.Value = productModel.SubCategoryId.ToString();

            ...


        }
```

And then i get the hiddenfield value and open accordion menu by jquery on the client side on document ready() function.

```
        var subCatId = $("#<%= hdnSubCategoryId.ClientID %>").val();
        var catId = $("#<%= hdnCategoryId.ClientID %>").val();

        $("#nestedAccordion div[CategoryId='" + catId + "']").css("display", "block");
        $("#nestedAccordion div div[SubCategoryId='" + subCatId + "']").css("display", "block");
```